# Change window position with button HighStocks

Tags: javascript, html, highcharts

I have a Highstocks graph covering one month of data, like this one :
[image: graph covering one month of data]

The objective is to add a button to allow the user, after he performed a zoom on a certain period of time (for example a day), to move the window for the same period of time.

Illustration: **graph after zooming on one day**
[image: graph after zooming on one day]

**graph after clicking on the desired button "+1 day"**
[image: graph after clicking on the desired button]

I guess I have to add an event to the chart and link it to an HTML button. I'm new to JavaScript and Highcharts, and I don't see on which parameters I can play to move the zoomed window.

Any idea ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Of course it is possible to implement it. In order to do that, you need to define a logic which will calculate a few things which I will describe below.

Let's assume that the button always should increase the range on the right side if it is possible (namely, if the range is not greater than your maximum data value). In case, when it is not possible to increase the range on the right side, let's align the selected range to maximum possible value (maximum data), and try add this range on the left side. Finally, when there is no possibility to double current range, just set extremes equal to maximum and minimum values of your data.

To implement it in the best way, you can use `Axis.getExtremes()` and `setExtremes()` functions.

I made the function which behaves like described above, so please take a look at it:

```
btn.onclick = function() {
        var axis = chart.xAxis[0]
        var ext = axis.getExtremes()
        // Calculate by what range should axis range be increased. 
        var range = ext.max - ext.min 

        // Add calculated range to right
        var addRight = function() {
            axis.setExtremes(ext.min, ext.max + range)
        }
        // Add calculated range to left
        var addLeft = function() {
            axis.setExtremes(ext.min - range, ext.max)
        }
        // Align range to possible maximum data
        var alignToRightEdge = function() {
            axis.setExtremes(ext.min, ext.dataMax)
        }

        // Increase range on right side if it is possible,
        // otherwise add maximum possible value on the right side
        // and increase on the left. Finally, set maximum possible
        // extremes (basing on current data) on whole xAxis.
        if (ext.max + range < ext.dataMax) {
            addRight()
        } else if (ext.min - range > ext.dataMin) {
            alignToRightEdge()
            addLeft()
        } else {
            axis.setExtremes(ext.dataMin, ext.datamax)
        }
    }
```

**Live example:** https://jsfiddle.net/6jpn7zs2/

**API Reference:**

https://api.highcharts.com/class-reference/Highcharts.Axis#getExtremes

https://api.highcharts.com/class-reference/Highcharts.Axis#setExtremes

Comment: Great answer, thank you. To obtain a cleaner result I used the object "exporting" of the chart, which allows to add custom buttons directly into the chart.

Comment: Also, you can use `Renderer` class. Here is the documentation: https://api.highcharts.com/class-reference/Highcharts.SVGRenderer